# how to upload file at google drive in android when i implement throght it gallery

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i am working on google drive and try to intrgate in my app.lots of thing i have done.
first i craete SH1 key and then enable the drive api and then genrate the APP key.now i
 have implement this link but when i pick the image from gallery it redirect back on this activity and i print the path of image it gives correct path and doesn't uploading.
 what i do now??please anybody help me i m struck here what i do now cannot understand.

```
 https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_4_set_up_the_sample
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 3;
    private static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;

    private static Drive service;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;  
   private static Uri selectedImageUri;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView tv;
    Intent pictureintent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                         pictureintent = new Intent();
                         pictureintent.setType("image/jpeg");
                         pictureintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                         pictureintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
                         startActivityForResult(pictureintent, SELECT_PICTURE);

                    }
                }); 


    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode){
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                  credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                  service = getDriveService(credential);
                  saveFileToDrive();
                }
              }
              break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                saveFileToDrive();
              } else {
                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
              }

        case SELECT_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
               // tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                //tv.setText("File Path: " + selectedImagePath);
              showToast("File Path: " + selectedImagePath);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                //img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); 
                startpictureIntent();

        }

    }
}



    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
            .build();
      }

    public void startpictureIntent(){


        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);


    }



    private void saveFileToDrive() {

       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              // File's binary content
              java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(selectedImageUri.getPath());
              FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

              // File's metadata.
              File body = new File();
              body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
              body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

              File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
              if(file != null) {

                showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());

              }

            }catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            }   catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
        t.start();
      }



        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
             String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
             int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
             cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }  



         public void showToast(final String toast) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
                });
              }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too use almost the same code for uploading a pdf file, but it is working for me,

```
 try
      {
         FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/pdf",pdfFile);
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        body.setTitle(filename);
        body.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file =     servicer.files().insert(body,mediaContent).execute();
                     if (file != null)
                     {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File exported successfully", 2000);
                                 toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 30);
                                 toast.show();
                             }
                         }
                         );

                     }

                 }
                 catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e)
                 {
                     startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                 }
                 catch (IOException e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```